# Add secondary axis to stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code which creates the plot below

```
sec_axis_data <- mpg %>%
  group_by(manufacturer) %>%
  summarise(entries = n())

p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = manufacturer, fill = class == "compact")) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('blue', 'red')) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~. * 50))
p
```

[image]

However, I'm not sure how to get the secondary axis data to display properly as a line across the plot? When, for example, I try:

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = manufacturer, fill = class == "compact")) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('blue', 'red')) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~. * 50)) +
  geom_line(data = sec_axis_data, aes(x = manufacturer, y = entries))
p
```

... I get an error. I think the issue is linked to the different lengths of the data for mpg and sec_axis_data, but I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were quite close of the solution.

You need to add `inherit.aes = FALSE` because of the `fill` argument not find in your second dataframe.

Also, to set the appropiate value, you need to divide your "entries" values by the same ratio you used for building the second axis in `sec.axis` function:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = manufacturer, fill = class == "compact")) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('blue', 'red')) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~. * 50, name = "Second axis")) +
  geom_line(inherit.aes = FALSE, data = sec_axis_data, 
            aes(x = manufacturer, y = entries/50, group = 1), size = 2)
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Appreciate you toning down the colours as well! :)